# Angular 2+ Karma doesn't load main style-sheet referenced in .angular-cli.json file

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

Karma doesn't load stylesheet referenced in angular-cli.json file[image]

Comment: I think it's by design? Why would you need it? Generally, you wouldn't. What exactly are you trying to test that would require it? Just curious

Comment: In my case I wish to remove a Material alert saying a default theme is not loaded.